# My 240 GB SSD shown as having 2MB

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, multi-boot, ubuntu-16.04

I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad Z500.
My SSD harddrive is a 240GB Silicon Power S60.

On the SSD 2 operating systems were installed: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Last night I couldn't boot my PC and got the message:

> Operating system not found

I removed my SSD drive and connected it to another PC with a simple SATA cable.

When I checked the size of my drive it appeared to have only 2 MB:

[image: screenshot showing drive is only 2MB]

Is there a way to solve this or is my SSD failing?